# Store the result of for loop iteration in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Am new to Python and started learning it from some tutorials.

I have a for loop which stores the output in a dictionary. At the end of the code the dict is getting updated any only the result of last for loop iteration is stored. It's the basic functionality of the for loop and it's fine.

I just want to have all the values in the different dictionaries which are iterated from the for loop.

The below is my code

```
from collections import defaultdict
import glob
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/TestCase/Downloads/test/*'): 

    by_color = defaultdict(int)
    im = Image.open(file)
    for pixel in im.getdata():
        by_color[pixel] += 1
    by_color

    # Update the value of each key in a dictionary to 1
    d = {x: 1 for x in by_color}
    # Print the updated dictionary

    check = dict(d)

    print(check) // Print the results from the for loop

 print(check) // Prints only the last iteration result of for loop
```

EDIT:

From the answer posted below, am getting a list of dictionary with all the keys and values appended.

**Actual Output:**

```
[{(0, 255, 255): 1, (33, 44, 177): 1, (150, 0, 0): 1, (255, 0, 255): 1, (147, 253, 194): 1, (64, 0, 64): 1, {(0, 255, 255): 1, (33, 44, 177): 1, (150, 0, 0): 1, (96, 69, 143): 1, (255, 0, 255): 1}]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[{(0, 255, 255): 2, (33, 44, 177): 2, (150, 0, 0): 2, (96, 69, 143): 1, (255, 0, 255): 2, (147, 253, 194): 1, (64, 0, 64): 1}]
```

Comment: you have updated the value for same key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a list to store your dictionaries and add the dict at then end of each iteration. It would look like something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import glob
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

my_dicts = []

for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/TestCase/Downloads/test/*'): 

    by_color = defaultdict(int)
    im = Image.open(file)
    for pixel in im.getdata():
        by_color[pixel] += 1
    by_color

    # Update the value of each key in a dictionary to 1
    d = {x: 1 for x in by_color}
    # Print the updated dictionary

    check = dict(d)

    print(check) # Print the results from the for loop

    my_dicts.append(check)

print(my_dicts) # Prints the dictionaries stored in a list
```

**EDIT:** to answer your other question, you can use counters to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
from collections import defaultdictfrom
import glob
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

my_dicts = []

for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/TestCase/Downloads/test/*'): 

    by_color = defaultdict(int)
    im = Image.open(file)
    for pixel in im.getdata():
        by_color[pixel] += 1
    by_color

    # Update the value of each key in a dictionary to 1
    d = {x: 1 for x in by_color}
    # Print the updated dictionary

    check = dict(d)

    print(check) # Print the results from the for loop

    my_dicts.append(check)

my_counters = [Counter(d) for d in my_dicts]

res = Counter()
for c in my_counters:
    res += c
output = dict(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and this looks fine. Can I sum the values in the append statement for the same keys in different dict?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the desired output? Do you want only one dictionary containing the values of each loop?

Comment: I just modified the question from your answer. I added the actual and the desired result

Comment: Thanks a lot Silveris for the quick response